# the root lattice, reflections, and a coxeter element

Tags: co.combinatorics, coxeter-groups, root-systems, reflection-groups

**Question:** Is is possible to realise the positive root lattice $\Phi_{\Delta}^{>0}$ (viewed as an abstract poset) of a root system $\Phi_\Delta$ associated to a Dynkin or affine Dynkin diagram $\Delta$ in terms of the set of reflections of the corresponding Weyl group $W_\Delta$ together with a choice of coxeter element ? In other words is it possible to define
a partial order $\leq_{\, c}$ on the set of all reflections in $W_\Delta$ ---- depending only upon on a choice of coxeter element $c$ --- which is isomorphic to $\Phi_\Delta^{>0}$ as a poset.

Comment: I should qualify my question by requesting that the construction of $\leq_{\, c}$ should be systematic enough so that it can be implemented for a general coxeter group. best, A. Leverkühn.

Comment: In the Dynkin case this construction probably should be read off from the incidence graph of the associated Shi arrangement --- but as far as I know there is no general notion of the Shi arrangement for an arbitrary coxeter group. best, A. Leverkühn.

Comment: Concerning the lattice: do you mean the poset of positive roots with $\alpha \leq \beta$ if $\beta - \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \Delta$ with simple system $\Delta$? This poset is not a lattice. Or do you mean its distributive lattice given by all order ideals ordered by containment?

Comment: In finite types, the later is indeed the adjacency graph of the regions *inside the positive Weyl chamber* of the Shi arrangement. The connections to noncrossing partitions and other constructions using Coxeter elements are still very mysterious, even in finite type. Two relevant references might be arxiv.org/abs/1101.1277 (warning: self-reference! describes the only known uniformly described bijection), arxiv.org/abs/math/0612219 (Section 3.3 deals with finite and affine types).

Comment: Dear Christian --- yes, I mean the poset structure which you refer to; and no, it's not a lattice. Indeed I am interested in the poset of ideals which I want to think of exclusively in terms of the coxeter interval --- without recourse to the root system which of course won't exist in general. Thanks for you comment. A. Leverkühn.

Comment: Why do you then call it "positive root lattice"?

Comment: Lattice in the demotic sense --- in type A it's half a square lattice.

Comment: There is a different paper of Christian's which is relevant to the motivation for the question: http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2876.  According to this paper, there is no reasonable candidate for a "poset of positive roots" in $H_4$ (though note that there are reasonable candidates for dihedral groups and for $H_3$, due to Drew Armstrong).  Thus, the hope that one could carry out the procedure for non-crystallographic Coxeter groups seems doomed.  (I still think it's an interesting question on its own merits, though.)

Comment: It's not so much a notion of positive root that I'm looking for --- simply a poset whose ideal structure returns the notion and basic properties of non-nesting partitions.

Comment: The subject of the paper by Christian (and Michael Cuntz) that I referred to in my previous comment is exactly the question of whether it is possible to find a poset associated to $H_4$ "whose ideal structure returns the notion and basic properties of non-nesting partitions".